# Producer Delegator Consumer using mutex

Tags: operating-system, mutex, semaphore

There are multiple consumers/listeners which produce/listen for  messages in Bounded buffer. There are multiple producers which produce messages in Bounded buffer. Delegator stores messages in its internal queue and process it according to its priority and sends them to appropriate listeners. Consumers accepts  messages according to predefined key. Message is in form of (key,value) pairs.
So consumer can consume messages if message's key matches with consumer's key.

This is a design problem , i was asked in an interview.
I used classical producer/consumer approach to solve it.
I want to know how delegator will fit into classical scenario and how mutexes will be handled ?

Comment: Flagging as off-topic!